# Симитировать нажатие на ссылку с атрибутом download

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

У меня есть такая разметка

```
<a class="el-3 fl-r js-xls-export" href="javascript: void(0);"></a>
<a class="el-2 fl-r" href="#"></a>
<a class="el-1 fl-r" href="#"></a>
<a href="#" class="" id="js-link-download" style="display:block;" download>link</a>
```

По нажатию на js-xls-export

```
$j(function(){
    $j('.js-xls-export').click(function(){

        $j.ajax({
            url: "/brand/productdiller/ajax/",
            dataType: "json",
            //type: "POST",
            data: {
                lines: 15,
                row: 3
            },
            success: function(data) {
                //location = 'http://mizol.shop'+data;
                //$j('body').append('<iframe class="hiddenFrame">'+data+'</iframe>');
                //window.open(data,'','…');
                console.log('succsess');
                //console.log(data);
                $j('#js-link-download').attr('download', 'http://mizol.shop'+data);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    alert(2);
                    $j('#js-link-download').trigger('click');
                    $j('#js-link-download').click();
                    //document.getElementsByClassName('js-link-download')
                    //console.log($j('.js-link-download').attr('download'));
                }, 1000);

                //console.log($j('.js-link-download').text());
            },
        });
    });
});
```

(в ответ приходит ссылка на скачивание файла)
Я ее тулю в js-link-download  и пытаюсь сымитировать нажатие на нее, но не получается, .click() не рабоатет.

Можно ли вообще для ссылки с атрибутом download сымитировать собитие click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно полян вашу проблему и основываясь на [ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21334234/1646082) вам надо сделать так:

```
$j('#js-link-download')[0].click();
```

Если же вам надо сделать что-то другое с кликом, уверен следи ответов по ссылке есть то, что вам надо.

Comment: Помогло, благодарю

Comment: Правда не понимаю в чем разница, ведь айди должен быть один...